# Administrador de usuarios de Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Estoy editando el código de WordPress para agregar un botones de subida de archivos pero no me los guarda en la bases de datos , ¿donde se podría modificar para que guarde en la bases de datos?,

modifique el archivo **edit-user** que viene con WordPress y solo adicione los botones para subir  archivos pero no me lo guarda en Bases de datos del usuario editado  ,los botones tiene una función jQuery para agregar varios botones para subir varios archivos y eliminar un archivo

**BOTONES**

```
<div id="main">
    <label for="subir"Archivo</label>
    <input type="button" id="btAdd" value="Añadir Archivo" class="bt" />
    <input type="button" id="btRemove" value="Eliminar Archivo" class="bt" />
    <input type="button" id="btRemoveAll" value="Eliminar Todo" class="bt" /><br />
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var iCnt = 0;

// Crear un elemento div añadiendo estilos CSS
var container = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
padding: '5px', margin: '20px', width: '170px', border: '1px dashed',
borderTopColor: '#999', borderBottomColor: '#999',
borderLeftColor: '#999', borderRightColor: '#999'
});

$('#btAdd').click(function() {
if (iCnt <= 19) {

iCnt = iCnt + 1;

// Añadir caja de texto.
$(container).append('<input input type="file" name="archivo" class="input" id=tb' + iCnt + ' ' +
'value="Elemento de Texto ' + iCnt + '" />');

if (iCnt == 1) {

var divSubmit = $(document.createElement('div'));
$(divSubmit).append('<input type=button class="bt" onclick="GetTextValue()"' +
'id=btSubmit value=Enviar />');

}

$('#main').after(container, divSubmit);
}
else { //se establece un limite para añadir elementos, 20 es el limite

$(container).append('<label>Limite Alcanzado</label>');
$('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt-disable');
$('#btAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

}
});

$('#btRemove').click(function() { // Elimina un elemento por click
if (iCnt != 0) { $('#tb' + iCnt).remove(); iCnt = iCnt - 1; }

if (iCnt == 0) { $(container).empty();

$(container).remove();
$('#btSubmit').remove();
$('#btAdd').removeAttr('disabled');
$('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt')

}
});

$('#btRemoveAll').click(function() { // Elimina todos los elementos del contenedor

$(container).empty();
$(container).remove();
$('#btSubmit').remove(); iCnt = 0;
$('#btAdd').removeAttr('disabled');
$('#btAdd').attr('class', 'bt');

});
});
```

Comment: Te falta toda la parte PHP que se encarga de guardar en la base de datos, puedes hacerlo con AJAX desde el propio jquery.

Comment: Oye gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Puedes usar el plugin ACF este ya tiene contemplado lo que indicas